# Issues when using JSON.dumps on an array

Tags: python, json

I'm creating a payload to send as body on an POST request. I Try to add some floats to a list within a dict. When the values are static everything is ok, but when I add the floats within the list as variable. `json.dumps()` convert them to a string.

**Example with static values**

```py
 payload = json.dumps({
        "_geo": {
            "intersects": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    4.895168,
                    52.370216
                ]
            }
        }
    })

    print(payload)
```

print result:

```
{"_geo": {"intersects": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [4.895168, 52.370216]}}}
```

**Example with variables**

```py
 latitude = 4.895168
 longitude = 52.370216

 payload = json.dumps({
        "_geo": {
            "intersects": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    latitude,
                    longitude
                ]
            }
        }
    })
```

print result

```
{"_geo": {"intersects": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": ["4.895168", "52.370216"]}}}
```

**The problem**

As you can see when using variables, the floats are converted to strings. How can I make the result the same as with static values?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this (Python 3.10.7). Floats are printed without quotes in both cases. Are you sure your `latitude` and `longitude` variables are actually of `float` type?

Comment: Also failing to reproduce, is this actually the code you are running or did you simplify the cause of your issue away on accident?

Comment: Never mind, I use typing within my function and assumed that the following line wouldn't allow string types, but it did. A simple float parse did the trick. 

`def read_plannen_by_lat_long(latitude: float, longitude: float):`